# Microsoft.Quantum.Canon.nuspec missing

Tags: q#

I am playing around with Microsoft's Q# library, and I've gone through the [install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quantum-installconfig?view=qsharp-preview), however the build is failing and I am having a tough time figuring out the problem. My first suspicion is Microsoft.Quantum.Canon

```
EXEC : error QS1001: Assembly E:\Projects\Quantum\Microsoft.Quantum.Canon\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Quantum.Canon.dll not found
```

I also have noticed Microsoft.Quantum.Canon.nuspec is missing. I've tried to do a `Nuget.exe restore` on the solutions but that did not work.

Has anyone worked through this?

[image: missing]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's been reported on GitHub already](https://github.com/Microsoft/Quantum/issues/10), although it appears to be intentional. See the comments in the .gitignore file:

```
# These files are generated by bootstrap from a .v.template (version template). 
# Any changes must be done to the corresponding the .v.template file directly
Microsoft.Quantum.Canon/Microsoft.Quantum.Canon.nuspec
```

I can't find any info on this `.v.template` file, probably it's part of internal Microsoft build tooling. You can copy the template file and fill in the missing parameters if you wish, but the file not existing doesn't make the build fail , does it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is causing the build to fail but my first guess is it has something to do with the Microsoft.Quantum.Canon and the first this standing out was the missing file. I will update my question with more info.

Comment: I attempted to try it out again but this time using VS Code and it worked.